# Submit Form with jQuery crashes the browser

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit form with jQuery but sometime it hangs the browser and sometime it crash. I am using jQuery validate plugin and I want to submit form when validation get passed. Is it possible that I submit form normally after validation pass, I don't want to submit with jQuery

Here is my little code snippet.

```
  var validate = function () {

        $('#contactForm').validate({           
            rules: {
                'first-name': {
                    required: true
                },
                'sur-name': {
                    required: true
                }
            },           
            submitHandler: function (form) {

                $('#contactForm').submit();

                return false;
            }
        });
    };

    $('#submitEnquiryForm').click(validate);
```

Comment: I hope the browser is not IE6.

Comment: What browsers have you tested in? Which of them work and which crash? You can try finding out where exactly it crashes by placing some `console.log()` in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the validation passes (*which listens to the submit event*) and you trigger the `submit` event again and again.

```
submit -> validate -> submit -> validate -> ... -> crash(maximum call stack size exceeded)
```

Try:

```
form.submit();
```

or:

```
$('#contactForm')[0].submit();
```

Which will submit the form normally and doesn't call the `validate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it instead of jquery.validate:

```
<style>
    .error {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="contactForm" action="javascript:alert('submitted')">
      <input type="text" id="first-name"/>
      <input type="text" id="sur-name"/>
      <input type="submit" />
   </form>
</body>

<script>
   $('#contactForm').submit(function (event) {

      fname = $('#first-name');
      sname = $('#sur-name');

      if (!fname.val())
      {
         fname.addClass('error');
         event.preventDefault();
      }
      else
      {
         fname.removeClass('error');
      }       

      if (!sname.val())
      {
         sname.addClass('error');
         event.preventDefault();
      }
      else
      {
         sname.removeClass('error');
      }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use .Off() event in jquery. The .off() method removes event handlers
>   that were attached with .on().

```
$('#submitEnquiryForm').off("click").on("click" , validate);
```

Comment: Is this assuming that he's gotten stuck in an infinite "submit" loop?

Comment: Sometime, it crashed most of the time it submit the form..Any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your code when you click `#submitEnquiryForm` validate `#contactForm` and submit it. ¿ok?

`submitHandler` function is called when you submit the form so you are in an infinite loop; submit event triggers submit again.

You don't need de call to `submit` in `submitHandler`.

I think it must be:

```
 $('#contactForm').validate({           
    rules: {
        'first-name': {
            required: true
        },
        'sur-name': {
            required: true
        }
    }
});

$('#submitEnquiryForm').click(function(){
    $('#contactForm').submit();
});
```

That validate the form when submit event is triggered, if you want to use click on `#submitEnquiryForm` instead of its submit buttom. The `submitHandler` function is for other purpouses as if you want to do other operations or tests before submit.

Comment: No, this won't change the behavior. Inside or outside the `submitHandler` doesn't matter.

Comment: I said "instead of its submit buttom", so I asume that click on `#submitEnquiryForm` triggers the submit and validation plugin manages it. I've avoided the loop... if `#submitEnquiryForm` is not the submit buttom. If it's the submit buttom we are looping again.